# Initial token position in axon kafka extension

Tags: axon, axon-framework

I'm using Axon kafka extension (4.5.4) to receive events from multiple sources (MultiStreamableMessageSource). How can I set initial token position (head) for StreamableMessageSource?

With this configuration

```
val config = TrackingEventProcessorConfiguration.forSingleThreadedProcessing()
        .andInitialTrackingToken { it.createHeadToken() }
```

i get **UnsupportedOperationException**.

As far as I understand, I need to write a custom implementation of creating a KafkaTrackingToken in the andInitialTrackingToken lambda. Is there an example? What if I don't know the specific partition offsets? Also, I have multiple MessageSource and it would look ugly.

PS. I know I could use SubscribableMessageSource, but that doesn't work for me, because I need to combine several MessageSources into one (like MultiStreamableMessageSource does)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not supported, not even with the latest, 4.7.0 version. In theory it should be possible, at least head, tail, and by timestamp. The [issue](https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-kafka/issues/30) to support those is now merged. So this will be supported from the 4.8.0 release, which should happen in a few months.

Currently, it will always default to offset 0, if there is no known offset. It's the [ConsumerSeekUtil](https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-kafka/blob/master/kafka/src/main/java/org/axonframework/extensions/kafka/eventhandling/consumer/ConsumerSeekUtil.java) that does this. With the pr, other tokens should be supported, which can move to a timestamp, or the end, when no offset is yet there.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but it didn't work unfortunately: @Bean
    fun authUserEventsAxonKafkaConsumerFactory(): ConsumerFactory<String, KafkaUserEvent> {
        val consumerConfiguration = KafkaProperties().apply {
            this.bootstrapServers = bootstrapServers
            this.consumer.autoOffsetReset = "latest"
        }.buildConsumerProperties()
        return DefaultConsumerFactory(consumerConfiguration)
    }

Comment: What didn't work about it? Maybe the offset was already stored in the token? It might also be it doesn't work with a `MultiStreamableMessageSource`?

Comment: I need a "head" token (in terms of kafka "latest" offset). The auto.offset.reset property doesn't work when configuring ConsumerFactory (for each MessageSource). I listed an example of creating a ConsumerFactory above. It's like the axon just ignores it and initializes the offset always with 0 position in each partition (of course I delete the saved token and kafka offset when testing this)

Comment: You are right. Currently, by using the [ConsumerSeekUtil](https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-kafka/blob/master/kafka/src/main/java/org/axonframework/extensions/kafka/eventhandling/consumer/ConsumerSeekUtil.java) it will bypass and configuration setting and start from the beginning, 0 offset. We could improve by creating the token in advance. We still have an [open issue](https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-kafka/issues/30), which I might pick up some time.

Comment: I just finished this [pr](https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-kafka/pull/403) to resolve the issue. Thereby, I'm pretty confident it will work from 4.8.0 (expected in a few months).